# Can someone please explain how those lines code works?

Tags: javascript

[Can someone please explain how those lines code works?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9YLN.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to copy and paste the code into your question instead of using an image? Use the `{}` option in the editor to format it. Also, please explain specific problems you are having understanding this code.

Comment: *"... but I don't fully understand it"* and that's where the question should start, not end. What is it, that you do not understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval()` executes function over and over. This function:

- Declares variable `birthday` with future date as a reference and
  converts it to special format (milliseconds since UNIX epoch)
- Declares variable `now` with current moment converted to same special
  format.
- Declares variable `distance` with difference between above two.
  That is, `distance` holds milliseconds left to birthday.
- Populates DOM elements (days, hours, minutes, seconds) with time left to birthday
- When difference becomes zero, it populates DOM elements (headline) with "It's my birthday" text and makes it visible (sets its `style` attribute) and at the same time makes counter invisible.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new on JavaScript but I just loved this code...
It looks clean, is there something we can do to make it simpler or easier to read?

Comment: What is the struggle with the code that's there? What about this is hard to read, from your perspective? It would help for guiding to some suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

it will continue running while the browser open, and will show :

> It's my birthday

on 30 september 2021 at 00:00:00